# update item in two dimensional array within the Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, computed-properties

I would like to get into VueJs development and created a simple Minesweeper game.The two dimensional grid is managed by a Vuex state. When clicking on a cell I would like to reveal it so my current code is

```
  [MutationTypes.REVEAL_CELL]: (state, { rowIndex, columnIndex }) => {
    state.board[rowIndex][columnIndex].isRevealed = true;
  }
```

Unfortunately this has no affect to the UI. This problem is known and described here

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

The docs told me to use something like this

```
import Vue from "vue";

  [MutationTypes.REVEAL_CELL]: (state, { rowIndex, columnIndex }) => {
    const updatedCell = state.board[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    updatedCell.isRevealed = true;

    Vue.set(state.board[rowIndex], columnIndex, updatedCell);
    Vue.set(state.board, rowIndex, state.board[rowIndex]);
  }
```

but it did not help. Lastly I tried to create a copy of the board, modify the values and assign that copy to the board.

```
  [MutationTypes.REVEAL_CELL]: (state, { rowIndex, columnIndex }) => {
    const newBoard = state.board.map((row, mapRowIndex) => {
      return row.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
        if (mapRowIndex === rowIndex && cellIndex === columnIndex) {
          cell = { ...cell, isRevealed: true };
        }
        return cell;
      });
    });

    state.board = newBoard;
  }
```

This didn't work neither. Does someone got an idea?

I created a Codesandbox showing my project

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-vuex-and-vuerouter-d4q2b

but I think the only relevant file is **/store/gameBoard/mutations.js** and the function **REVEAL_CELL**

Comment: Can you post the component code you're using Vuex in?

Comment: I just created a sandbox :)

Comment: It def looks like the grid is not reacting to state changes.. No idea why - still searching.. [I did find something interesting though.. if you click a cell and then click back into the code, and press any key (space, for example) the cell will show itself...](https://i.imgur.com/5CkLOfT.gif) - Even when I force a `commit` via the Vue Dev Tools it does not show the cell... very interesting issue...def seems like the 'board' change is not making its way to the necessary component.. Why not just handle that cell click from the cell component vs emitting that event all the way up like that?

Comment: ***Putting this here for visibility*** OP - please mark Dan's answer as correct - he is the one that figured this out - [here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuetify-vuex-and-vuerouter-keffd?fontsize=14&module=%2Fcomponents%2FCell.vue) - all I did was copy and paste what Dan said..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `Cell.vue` and the issue is that you're checking an unchanging variable to determine the state of reveal.  You've abstracted  `this.cell.isRevealed` into a variable called `isUnrevealed` which is never told how to change after the initial load.

**Option 1**

`isUnrevealed` seems like an unnecessary convenience variable.  If you get rid of `isUnrevealed` and change the references to it to `!cell.isRevealed`, the code will work as expected.

**Option 2**

If you're set on using this variable, change it to a computed so that it constantly updates itself whenever the Vuex state propagates a change to the `cell` `isRevealed` prop:

```js
computed: {
  isUnrevealed() {
    return !this.cell.isRevealed;
  }
}
```

If you go this route, don't forget to remove the property from `data` and remove the assignment in `mounted` (first line).

---

You'll also have the same problem with `isMine` and `cellStyle`.  So, completely remove `data` and `mounted` and make them both computed as well.

```js
computed: {
  isMine() {
    return this.cell.isMine;
  },
  cellStyle() {
    if (!this.cell.isRevealed) {
      return "unrevealedCell";
    } else {
      if (this.isMine) {
        return "mineCell";
      } else {
        let neighbourCountStyle = "";
        ... // Switch statement
        return `neutralCell ${neighbourCountStyle}`;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice find! This has me very curious... So I tested out option 1 - outside of the fact that whenever a bomb or neutral cell is clicked (the styles do not change - styles only change for the cell that was clicked), it is working perfectly..  I am trying to wrap my head around why this may be happening... any suggestions? It looks like `Grid.vue` is not reacting to the board changes.. (if a bomb or neutral cell is clicked and multiple cells need to be shown at once - they are still shown, they just aren't styled correctly)..

Comment: @MattOestreich - Thanks.  It's because the styles are never told to change -- all that code in `mounted` only runs once when the component is loaded.  To solve that, he could create another computed to determine the class, and move all the relevant code from `mounted` into it.

Comment: That was one thing I tried. I turned that mounted code into a function and I call it during mount as well as when the cell is clicked. I think I see what you mean though. Need to change the `cell.style` into a computed prop so it reacts to changes? Thanks for the input. I'll try to figure it out from here. Appreciate the response!

Comment: @MattOestreich - No problem. I just edited my answer to show that

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more than once lol - I hope OP gives you credit for this and chooses your answer as the accepted answer.  Oh...also... go ahead and [enjoy the fruits](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuetify-vuex-and-vuerouter-keffd?fontsize=14&module=%2Fcomponents%2FCell.vue) of your labor lol - it works flawlessly.  I dont know why I was letting `Vuex` clog my train of thought... ugh... At any rate, you helped me learn something and I appreciate that! Cheers